# Push Notification connection refused to APNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Am attempting to add push notifications to an application that I have created. I followed the apple guide and am able to register the device for post notifications receiving a devicetoken value from APNS. The trouble occurs when I attempt to send data to the APNS to send, I always have my connection refused.

The only thing that i have done that is non standard is that the private key for the push notification certificate was created by a non-team agent (but through the Team agents account). Does anyone know if the team agent has to generate the private key for the push notification?

Comment: Are you using development or ad hoc prov. profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason that you want to setup your own push notification server? You can just use [Urbanairship](http://www.urbanairship.com/) which provides free push notification services.

If you still need to set up your own server, info on generating your certificates can be found [here](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/). Make sure that you're connecting to the right push server on Apple's side. There are different server's for debugging and production purposes.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, it turns out that it was my network that was preventing the connection. When I connected outside that network it work first time :-) Excellent link to Urbanairship

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ad Hoc prov. profile, don't use sandbox apns, use the production server.

Both team agents and admins should have their private keys on their machines, they should be able to create the necessary certificates.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, it turns out that it was my network that was preventing the connection. When I connected outside that network it work first time :-)